# Django with celery in Docker Env

Tags: django, docker, celery

I have confusion whilst setting up django as docker container.

Basically there's celery and celery beat. If i understand correctly celery beat is a scheduler so it needs to be only initialised once.

So when horizontally scaling using AWS ECS using docker image i can put django and celery inside same image as celery worker but not celery beat. Is this assumption correct?

Also would it be good idea to have seperate celery image?

I have 4 queues inside django app and i believe each one will need atleast one celery worker.

Comment: It's a common enough setup to run the Django application and Celery workers off of the same image, just overriding the specific command when you run the container.

Answer (score 1):

You can put everything in the same docker-compose environment, if you have a powerful machine that can handle everything then it's not a bad idea. Also, you can put celery worker, beat even celery flower in the same compose file. Here's an example of what we do in production

Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.11.0-bullseye

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev build-essential

RUN pip install pipenv

COPY Pipfile Pipfile
COPY Pipfile.lock Pipfile.lock

RUN pipenv install

COPY ./django_app./appdjango_app
WORKDIR django_app
```

docker-compose file

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  # Main Django Application
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      command: "gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4"
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    deploy:
      replicas: 2

  
  # Celery beat scheduler, sends tasks to queue
  celery_beat:
    build:
      context: .
    command: "pipenv run celery -A app beat"
    env_file:
      - .env

  # Default celery consumer queue | Default, All tasks come to this consumer
  celery_default:
    build:
      context: .
    deploy:
      replica: 4 # 4 Workers  
    command: "pipenv run celery -A app worker -Q celery -l info --concurrency 16 --pool threads -n default@%h"
    env_file:
      - .env
  # Handle database work queue 
  celery_db:
    build:
      context: .
    deploy:
      replica: 4 # 4 Workers  
    command: "pipenv run celery -A app worker -Q db -l info --concurrency 16 --pool threads -n db@%h"
    env_file:
      - .env
  # Flower to monitor celery
  flower:
    image: mher/flower
    command: 'celery flower --broker=${CELERY_BROKER_URL} flower --port=5555'
    expose:
      - 5555
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    env_file:
      - .env
  

    
volumes:
  certbot-web:
  proxy-dhparams:
  certbot-certs:
```

In the compose file, the proxy and certbot is responsible for serving the web app, meanwhile there are workers working connected by the same Broker service and same Database

Comment: This cannot be considered as a production-grade Docker configuration. Your Celery worker should be deployed in a way that can be scaled horizontally. Looking at the above code, it is good for a quick development environment but not suitable for a production environment. It is also recommended to use production-grade orchestration tools like Kubernetes for spinning up Docker images instead of Docker Compose.